# Dynamically hiding / showing Field API fields in Drupal 7

Tags: entities

I've created an entity with an 'add new' form. The entity itself has a limited number of actual variables. I've added most of the extra data I need using custom Fields (i.e. the Field API).

What I need to do at this stage is be able to dynamically hide one field based on the value of another. i.e. if a drop-down field has it's value set to No, another field should be hidden, otherwise it should be shown.

From what I can see, it is somewhat easy to add this functionality to fields created using the Form API (i.e. via the AJAX property), however is there any way to achieve it using attached fields? I have no issues using custom Javascript if that is what is required to solve this.

Comment: I'm not sure if http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields is ready to go for d7 yet, but it might be worth looking into

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery works well for this:

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#select1').change(function() {
      switch ($(this).val()) {
        case '1':
          $('#field2').hide();
          break;
        default:
          $('#field2').show();
          break;
      }
    });
  });
}) (jQuery);
```

Comment: Yeah, I ended up using drupal_add_js on the form page and ended up doing it in jQuery. I was just wondering whether there was a more 'Drupal' way to do this.

Comment: I would mention that I'm not a big fan of the Drupal #states approach to visibility, which is why I didn't suggest it above.

Comment: @keithm Could you elaborate please on why you're not a fan of states (as of 2015, D7). I'm working on a project where we're trying to make the decision to use #states vs drupal_add_js. Why do you think one is a better choice over the other?

Comment: It's a matter of legitimate programmer preference in my opinion; my rationale may differ from yours. That said, in practice I rather dislike resorting to another syntax that duplicates functionality found in Javascript/jQuery. When I have tried #states, I also found the use cases for which it is apparently designed too limiting. When my problem extended outside these use cases, I had to rewrite the whole thing in straight Javascript anyway.

Answer (score 19):

In Drupal 7, Drupal 8 you can use $form `#states` instead of custom jQuery script. Example:

```
  $form['student_type'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#options' => array(
      'high_school'   => t('High School'),
      'undergraduate' => t('Undergraduate'),
      'graduate'      => t('Graduate'),
    ),
    '#title' => t('What type of student are you?')
  );

  // High school information.
  $form['high_school']['tests_taken'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#options' => drupal_map_assoc(array(t('SAT'), t('ACT'))),
    '#title' => t('What standardized tests did you take?'),
    // This #states rule says that this checkboxes array will be visible only
    // when $form['student_type'] is set to t('High School').
    // It uses the jQuery selector :input[name=student_type] to choose the
    // element which triggers the behavior, and then defines the "High School"
    // value as the one that triggers visibility.
    '#states' => array(
      'visible' => array(   // action to take.
        ':input[name="student_type"]' => array('value' => 'high_school'),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Here is example if you want to use `#states` for multiple values condition:

```
 $form['student_type'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#options' => array(
      'high_school'   => t('High School'),
      'undergraduate' => t('Undergraduate'),
      'graduate'      => t('Graduate'),
    ),
    '#title' => t('What type of student are you?')
  );

  // High school information.
  $form['high_school']['tests_taken'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('What standardized tests did you take?'),
    '#states' => array(
      'visible' => array(   // action to take.
        ':input[name="student_type[high_school]"]' => array('checked' => TRUE),
        ':input[name="student_type[undergraduate]"]' => array('checked' => TRUE),
        ':input[name="student_type[graduate]"]' => array('checked' => FALSE),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

See the `form_example/form_example_states.inc` from [examples module](http://drupal.org/project/examples) for more details and examples.

Comment: Speaking of `#states`, I've never found a way to define more complex visibility conditions, such as: hide control A when control B value is in array(x,y,z). Do you happen to know a syntax for that?

Comment: See my update above

Answer (score 4):

You should try [Conditional Fields](http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields), I think this module is a must-have for this task. You can set dependencies between fields on a user-friendly admin interface. For example, you can set `A` field to be only *visible* if `B` field has value "*1234*", or you can set `C` textfield to be *visible* only when `D` field is checked, or set `E` field to *invisible* if `F` is *focused* etc.

On the upload form, these dependencies will be set client-side, on node display, these dependencies will be set on the server-side.

You can set these dependencies at `admin/structure/types/manage/[YOURCONTENTTYPESMACHINENAME]/dependencies`.

[image: Conditional Fields]
<sub>(Source of the image: the project's [page](http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields))</sub>